# Retrieving other information on CountryData

Tags: curated-data

The following input will produce some answers, however how do we find out other details, such as the specific year the result corresponds to, as well as the source from which the data is obtained?

```
CountryData["France", "MaleElderlyPopulation"]

CountryData["Australia", "MaleElderlyPopulation"]
```

Comment: Not sure why this was tagged [tag:numerical-value] and [tag:social-media].  Feel free to roll back if there's a need to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Referring to the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CountryData.html):

```
CountryData["France", "MaleElderlyPopulation", "Date"]

(* 2013 *)
```

The annotation (3rd argument) provides the date and general source information is [provided here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/note/CountryDataSourceInformation.html).

Comment: I note that none of the listed sources dates from after 2008, so this actually doesn't source the above piece of information...

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries shame on me for not checking the validity of the sources.  I went with the old "if it's on the internet, it must be true" adage.

Comment: I notice that  the input requiring data for a range of years work well only for some attributes. For instance, the command given below goes well, whereas if I replace "GDP" by "MaleElderlyPopulation", it  complains.                                                                                                                                                                        
DateListPlot[{CountryData["Australia", {{"GDP"}, {1970, 2012}}],   CountryData["France", {{"GDP"}, {1970, 2012}}]},  PlotLegends -> {"Australia", "France"}]

Answer (score 4):

For what it is worth: If you formulate the query as a Wolfram Alpha query you get

```
WolframAlpha["male elderly population in France", {{"Result", 1}, "Content"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So, apparently this estimate dates from 2013.

As to the sources used: If you enter `==` at the beginning of the line you get a W|A box in which you can enter the same string ("male elderly population in France") as above. If you click on the "+" button next to the Wolfram Alpha icon on the bottom right of the resulting W|A pod you can choose a [link to the sources](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/sources.jsp?sources=CountryData).

I assume results of W|A and `CountryData` will be tapped from the same source.